# Sweetalert Loading Screen Before .withsuccesshandler

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, frontend, sweetalert2

i'm integrating sweetalert2 in my Google Workspace Addon. The code is simple.

Functions for sucess and error.

```
<script>
function swalsuccess() {

Swal.fire({
  title: '¡Hecho!',
  text: 'El script se ha ejecutado ',
  icon: 'success',
  confirmButtonText: 'Continuar'
})

}
</script>

<script>
function swalerror() {

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Error!',
  text: 'El script no ha podido ejecutarse.',
  icon: 'error',
  confirmButtonText: 'Entendido'
})

}
</script>
```

And a button that executes a function onclick, with the "withsuccesshandler" and "withfailurehandler" to show if the script has been applied to the Google Sheet document.

```
<button class="button-68" role="button" onclick="morphf354()">Eliminar filas (Max.k)</button>

<script>
function morphf354() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(swalsuccess)
  .withFailureHandler(swalerror)
  .deleteRows();
}
</script>
```

Well, the script takes few seconds to realise the function, so i want to add a loading swal screen, that changes to swalsuccess when it's done.
I don't know how to implement it and I don't know how to fit my code with the solutions that i read on the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Fire a loader dialog before making the `google.script.run`
- Close it in the success handler

```
function swalsuccess() {
    Swal.close()
    Swal.fire({
      title: '¡Hecho!',
      text: 'El script se ha ejecutado ',
      icon: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'Continuar'
    })
}
function morphf354() {
    Swal.fire({
      titleText: "Checking data...",
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      preConfirm: Swal.showLoading,
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    })
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(swalsuccess)
      .withFailureHandler(swalerror)
      .deleteRows();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set timerinterval for `Swal` to be fired

```
function swalsuccess() {
let timerInterval
Swal.fire({
      title: '¡Hecho!',
      text: 'El script se ha ejecutado ',
      icon: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'Continuar'
        timer: 4000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: () => {
            Swal.showLoading()
            timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                const content = Swal.getHtmlContainer()
                if (content) {
                    const b = content.querySelector('b')
                    if (b) {
                        b.textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
                    }
                }
            }, 100)
        },
        willClose: () => {
            clearInterval(timerInterval)
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
    }
})
```